# Not change the color fo the application in WP8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my setting page I have a `listPicker` control, that have two values `Dark` and `Light` when I select `Dark` from `listpicker` I want to change background to `Silver` foreground color to `white` buttons background color to `Black`, buttons foreground color to `white` and accentcolor is `black` of the application, and I am doing like below:

```
private void themelistPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListPickerItem lpi = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem as ListPickerItem;
            themename = lpi.Content.ToString();
            if (themename == "Dark")
            {
                SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
                brush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 192, 192);
                App.RootFrame.Background = brush;

                ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"]).Color = Colors.Black;
                ((Color)Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"])= Colors.Black;
            }
            else 
            {
                SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
                brush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
                App.RootFrame.Background = brush;

                ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"]).Color = Colors.Blue;
                ((Color)Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"])= Colors.Black;
            }
```

But it changes only the background and accentcolor color of the setting's page not all the application and also not change the foreground and buttons color of the application, why?

Kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.

Thanks

Comment: try => (App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).COlor = Colors.Black;

Answer (score 0):

For doing this, define in App.xaml your custom SolidColorBrushes and then set them as Background/Foreground to all your controls. Then just change those Brushes and it will change all the controls.

Do not change colors to the system defined brushes, because all controls use them. That is why your code changes things you don't want to be changed.